# Length Cannot be zero vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi is there away to detect the length of a byte before I get the error message:

Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length

I get the error on this line:

new_username = new_username.Substring(0, new_username.IndexOf(" Joined "))

I am removing the "joined" from the string I get....how can I ignore it is "joined" isnt the the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would test to see what IndexOf returned before using it in this context:

```
if(new_username.IndexOf(" Joined") > 0)
{
      new_username = new_username.Substring(0, new_username.IndexOf(" Joined "))
}
```

Comment: That's inefficient since you're calling IndexOf twice.  Best to call once and cache it for use in both places.

Comment: It's probably worth checking the MSIL before doing that optimization - I think the compiler can optimise the second call away where there are no side-effects.

Comment: @ctake forgive my ignorance, but how would you do that ? Create a new variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_username = new_Username.Replace(" Joined ", "")
```

Be warned that this will remove *all* occurrences of the "`Joined`" substring rather than just the first.

Comment: If the initial string has only a username and the optional string " joined", with nothing else, this will work great!

Comment: Also provided no one has " joined" as part of their username :/

Comment: @Michael: .IndexOf()-based code would fail in that case as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `new_username.IndexOf(" Joined ")` is returning -1 meaning the string " Joined" was not found by `Substring`.  I would break this out into two statements:

The error you are seeing is that you are effectively making this call:

```
new_username = new_username.Substring(0, -1)
```